# Export Modern Team site as a JSONfile

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, json

I'm about to set up a new SPO env.
In the env I should have 5 custom templates, which powerusers can select in the dropdown list when creating a new teamsite.

I tried different tutorial and PS scripts but can seem to get it working.

- https://docfluix.com/2018/10/15/tips-tricks-for-automated-sharepoint-site-provisioning-with-pnp-part-1/ (works with XML files)
- https://laurakokkarinen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-site-designs-and-site-scripts/ (works well, but I have to manually compose the .JSON file)

I'm looking for a tool, better yet a PSscript for export a existing Teamsite as JSONtemplate.

Anyone to the rescue?

Answer (score 0):

If xml will do ( json is xml for hipsters ;-) then the PnP Provisioning engine might be what you are looking for : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine

Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate  in particular

Comment: Hi Kasper. The tutorial from docfluix works with XML. But how can i _publish_ this as a tenant teamsite template, with Add-SPOSiteDesign